# How to use BreakIterator to check 3 strings are located in a same sentence

Tags: java

I have 3 strings in a file with start and end index.

```
Start:127 stop:139 name:barackObama
Start:144 stop:148 name:born
Start:149 stop:163 name:August 4 1961
```

Now i got to check these 3 strings are in a same sentence or not by using BreakIterator.
BreakIterator splits the text into sentences with boundaries 0 to n. But here i have start an d end indexes of strings.How do i check these 3 strings located in a same sentence or not by using start and stop indexes.

I tried to print sentences splitted by BreakIterator

```
BreakIterator i=BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(Locale.US);
i.setText(text);//HTML page text
for(int s=i.first(), e=i.next(); e>=0; s=e, e=i.next())
{
  System.out.println("Sentence: from "+s+" to "+e+" \""+text.substring(s, e)+'"');
 }
```

It prints all HTML lines in the following manner

```
Sentence: from 0 to 2 "<!"
Sentence: from 2 to 15 "DOCTYPE html>"
Sentence: from 0 to 46 "<html lang="en" dir="ltr" class="client-nojs">"
Sentence: from 0 to 6 "<head>"
**Sentence: from 0 to 95 "<dd><a href="/wiki/Barack_Obama" title="BarackObama">Barack    Obama</a> born August 4, 1961</dd>"**
Sentence: from 0 to 5 "</dl>"
Sentence: from 0 to 5 "</dd>"
```

Comment: As you iterate through sentences using BreakIterator (getSentenceInstance), check the boundaries of current sentence, and test if your string's start and stop are within it.

Comment: The sentence printed by BreakIterator 0 to 95 has the 3 strings those i am trying to check.But the boundaries are 0 and 95.But my string start and ens index are 127 and 163.